# How to Extend Construct Method from Parent Class

Tags: php, oop

I have created a construct method in my User Class:

```
class User {
    protected $name;
    protected $title;

    public function __construct($name = null, $title = null) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

Now I want to extend the construct method within my Client Class. After "experimenting" with multiple code blocks I don't seem to be able to get my head around how to do this. I want $company to be included with initialization. Here is the latest version of my unsuccessful code:

```
class Client extends User
{
  protected $company;  

  public function __construct($company = null)
  {      
    parent::__construct($name = null, $title = null);
    $this->company = $company;   
  }

  public function getCompany()
  {        
    return $this->company;
  }

  public function setCompany($company)
  {    
    $this->company = $company;
  }
}

$MyPHPClassSkillLevel = newbie;
```

I'm really just scratching the surface of extending classes so any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is it doing or not doing?  It looks like it should at least work, maybe not how you intend but we don't know.

Comment: The `Client` constructor should probably accept `$name` and `$title` arguments, so it can pass them along when constructing the parent.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget: In order to develop a good OOP solution, you need to have a good understanding of the so-called **S.O.L.I.D. principles**! There are more, too (DRY, KISS, etc), but the SOLID ones are the core of the OOP.

Comment: I'll check out the SOLID principles, good advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `User` class is perfect. The `Client` class is almost perfect: you just need to pass the same constructor arguments (`$name` and `$title`) to the subclass `Client` too. And try to also use the setters, if you define them - like `$this->setCompany($company)`.

```
class Client extends User
{
  protected $company;  

  public function __construct($company = null, $name = null, $title = null)
  {      
    parent::__construct($name, $title);
    $this->setCompany($company);   
  }

  public function getCompany()
  {        
    return $this->company;
  }

  public function setCompany($company)
  {    
    $this->company = $company;
  }
}
```

When you DEFINE parameters, you can make them optional - what you already did in `User`:

```
public function __construct($name = null, $title = null) {
    //...
}
```

But, when you PASS arguments, e.g. valulues for the defined parameters, then is not valid to pass them as "optional". So, in class `Client`, this is not valid:

```
parent::__construct($name = null, $title = null);
```

But this it is:

```
parent::__construct($name, $title);
```

I would also recommend you this: [The Clean Code Talks - Don't Look For Things!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) (just to be sure).

Comment: I'm glad i could helped. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @aendeerei!

Comment: @jpradcliffe You are welcome. I just wrote you another small but important comment to your original question. Feel free to ask further, ok? Bye